# Permissão de admin para executar netsh em java

Tags: java, windows, firewall

Em um programa em java que desenvolvi, preciso abrir conexão na porta 21 (ftp) mas o Windows 7 por padrão bloqueia esta porta. 
Tentei adicionar uma regra no firewall permitindo a conexão usando Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“netsh ...”), mas netsh precisa de permissão de admin. Tem como em java invocar uma janela solicitando a permissão?

Answer (score 2):

Bom, há algumas maneiras para se fazer isto pelo que se deu a entender pela sua pergunta.

**1 - Criando um manifesto**

Você precisa criar um arquivo manifesto que especifica que sua aplicação necessita de permissões de administração. Você pode incluir este manifesto dentro do seu `exe` ou deixar separado do seu arquivo (seuapp.exe.manifest).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

http://mark.koli.ch/uac-prompt-from-java-createprocess-error740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation

**2- Runas**

> Runas permite que um usuário execute ferramentas e programas específicos com permissões diferentes do que o logon atual do usuário fornece.

Há uma diferença entre estar conectado a uma conta que faz parte do grupo de administradores e executando (a) elevado ou (b) como a conta Administrador incorporada.

Sempre que você executar como Administrador, você sempre é elevado - por definição. Portanto, se você executar `/ user: administrador` esta janela será elevada quando abre, você não receberá um prompt UAC e o comando netsh deve ser executado.

Mas como a conta Administrador integrada sempre é executada em níveis elevados e não gera prompts UAC de runas, é um risco de segurança, especialmente se não tiver uma senha. É por isso que a Microsoft desativa a conta de administrador por padrão e requer que você a habilite primeiro:

> No Windows® 7, a conta de administrador integrada está desativada por padrão. Em versões anteriores do Windows, uma conta de administrador foi criada automaticamente durante Out-of-Box-Experience (OOBE) com uma palavra-passe em branco.
>
> Uma conta de administrador com uma senha em branco é um risco de segurança. Para proteger melhor o sistema, a conta Administrador integrada é desabilitada por padrão em todas as instalações limpas e atualizações do Windows 7.

Por causa disto, você precisa ativar o modo Administrador, para isto, faça o seguinte :

```
Altere as propriedades da conta de administrador usando a Console de Gerenciamento Microsoft (MMC) de Usuários e Grupos Locais.

 1 - Abra o console do MMC e selecione Usuários e Grupos Locais.

 2- Clique com o botão direito do mouse na conta Administrador e selecione Propriedades. 

3 - A janela Propriedades do administrador é exibida. 

4 - Na guia Geral, desmarque a caixa de seleção Conta desativada. 

5 - Feche a consola MMC.
```

Além disso, esteja ciente de que runas NÃO permite que você passe argumentos para o programa executado:

```
RUNAS : 

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
 /user:<UserName> program 

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ] 
 /smartcard [/user:<UserName>] program 

RUNAS /trustlevel:<TrustLevel> program
```

**Exemplo simples**

O comando a seguir inicia uma instância do prompt de comando como um administrador no computador local:

```
runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator cmd
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx

**3 - Batch files**

Você pode usar um programa do Windows para elevar seus privilégios. O programa mostrará o prompt do UAC e, em seguida, você terá privilégios de administrador.

http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/

Você pode então executar para comando como este:

```
Runtime.getRuntime (). Exec ("Elevate.exe yourcommand");
```

**Informação extra :**

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29

> OBS : Caso tenha dúvidas referentes aos tópicos acima, só perguntar.